# How To Sort Array On Behalf Of Another When One Array Index Is Of String m Using array_intersect?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

as i have array like

```
  $array[selfintro,1]=[selfintroduction]]
  $array[experience,2]=[Experience]
  $array[education,3] =[Education]
  $array[skills,4]= [Skills]

  $model[]=[Education,selfintroduction,accomplishment]
```

i wanna sort "array"  using "model" array so it would be like,

```
$array[education,3] =[Education]
$array[selfintro,1]=[selfintroduction]]
```

i tried to sort it using this technique,

$sorted=array_intersect($model,$array);`

it do not sort it but when i do it using normal array ahving index value then it give me its result but by using $array its index value in string and int formamt not working for me ?

hopes for your suggestions,

EDITED::

i am populating array from mysqldb and this array contain data like i mentioned above

```
for loop
{
$array[$templateName.','.$inc]=$V_temptag;
}
```

after creating this array i sort it using another array that is $model

```
$sorted=array_intersect($model,$array);
print_r($sorted);
```

Comment: strange way to define an array ? also Question title is ambiguous

Comment: You want to sort it or rearrange it customly? And what is that code you provided?

Comment: Please post the right php code.

Comment: @all perhaps code have error but its index and values are same i am just telling you what i want to do and whats actually doing you all people are well aware of declaring array hopes for your suggestions

Comment: Since this is not valid PHP code by any stretch, it's hard to understand what you're really asking for. Please provide an *actual* sample.

Comment: put print_r or var_dump of your array created. so that we come to know what is the structure of array.Either your presentation is wrong or something else